# Creating many objects and recycling them

Tags: c#, design-patterns

**I want to create a class that will allow me to have many objects and store them in a data structure.** These objects will come out of the list do something then put back into the list. This cycle will repeat many times during the execution of the program for different objects always in this list.

I am highly interested in two aspects:

1. Creating/Building the many objects efficiently
2. Using them constantly

At the moment objects are created like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++)
   new WhitePlate(0,2,5);
```

**Is there a design pattern that will make this easy?** I am thinking, from what I read, that factory design pattern or builder would do the trick, which should I use.

**What design pattern do you recommend for me to use when I have to create many objects and keep them in a data structure?**

*The data structure I will use is trivial and does not matter to much, but I will use a Hash.*

Comment: A factory _creates_ objects. A builder _builds_ them. You're looking for something more like a circular buffer I'd say.. but perhaps just a normal list is what you're after?

Comment: Normal list or hash would do it, but I really care about an efficient way to create all these objects.

Comment: What kind of objects? If you're just talking about objects in general, I'd have to nominate "new objectName();" for most efficient...

Comment: If you're creating the pool once at startup, does it really matter how efficiently you create them?

Comment: Things you would find in a room, plates, chairs. This is all in a game. It does matter because of load time, now it takes from 2 to 3 mins on average. I have a class for each object. So I do a lot of for loops instantiating `new Plate(1,5,0)`

Comment: I really don't get what you mean - do you think .NET decided to have `new` as the inefficient keyword & someone will provide you a fancy one? If so, nobody will be able to give you that.

For your parent object... Read up on data structures or provide more info on your usage to determine if you want a List, a Dictionary, a Stack, or any of the other possible choices...

Comment: If it's taking 2-3 minutes, first run a performance profiler on your app, find the part that's using the time, then if you can't work out why ask about that & if there's a faster way to do that piece. There's no quick version of `new` for making objects or it'd always be used instead of new.

Comment: @user3626975 Well if you only need to specify an ID, X, Y, and possibly Z coordinates, then a struct could possibly be more efficient for passing to methods. Any data structure less than or equal to 16 bytes in size is potentially faster as a struct than a class. I can't think of any other object-creation-specific details that you can control.

Comment: @user3626975 You _might_ be able to store all that data as a byte array and then marshal them as an array of structs... it could potentially be faster IIRC. Something to look into if it's really that important.

Comment: @fyjham I am pretty sure you are being nonconstructive, when did I say I want something different to `new`? I am simply asking if there is a better way to make many objects of different types, perhaps with a design pattern...

Comment: Perhaps the answer is not declare everything all at once, and only create what is in view of the player, but hard to say without more information on what you are doing

Comment: You should look into the Object Pool Pattern http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope it is more clear now what my question is.

Comment: Given your edit - I am unsure how much easier you want that to be? That looks like a very straight forward way to declare a bunch of objects..

Comment: @user3626975 not being nonconstructive, you asked for a faster method & told us you're using `new`. I'm just saying no such thing exists. If you need better performance then this is the wrong spot to look.

I'd also go ahead and say anyone suggesting a design pattern is guessing, because the scope you've listed isn't enough to justify a design pattern beyond calling `new`. You indicated performance is your reason, so I suggested you may be going in the wrong direction here & suggested a Performance Profiler before making design decisions. Far from non-constructive I'd say...

Comment: @fyjham "you're trying to optimize before you know what's wrong." " would in fact place a bet that creating the objects isn't your problem". You make so many wild assumptions, I hope you realize that my objects are actually really expensive because they are in a game. Most are using 512x512 textures. But hey, don't worry about it, I'll call you when I need more assumptions.

Comment: So... this is the first time you mention that your objects are actually large picture files instead giving the impression they're a set of co-ordinates and that's my fault? Also, that seems to confirm my statement still, the creation of the objects isn't your performance overhead, the performance overhead is the loading of the textures which was never mentioned.

Having a go at people who offer help after asking vague questions really isn't a good way to get help. I'm out of this one.

Comment: I said they are objects in a game, you decided to assume they are just positions. Now you are assuming that the way I load the textures matters to my question, trust me it is more efficient than you can imagine. Why are you trying to solve a problem that DOESN'T exist? Again, my problem is I wanted a design pattern, besides Factory, to create objects. Your problem is you are assuming random things. Bye and stop commenting, you are bugging, the other people that actually helped, with your assumptions...

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing in your question is an **Object Pool.**

Object pools aren't exactly unprecedented.  I've seen them used in Java programs where the goal is to **eliminate garbage collection pressures.**  They work by creating an ordinary collection, populating that collection with objects, and then, instead of calling `new`, you simply grab an unused object from the collection.

Whether this will help your particular program is an open question.  You would have to try it the conventional way and the Object Pool way, run some tests, and see which way works better.  It goes without saying that the Object Pool is going to use more memory, but the *total amount of memory usage* will vary much less.

Answer (score 0):

[Prototype](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) is a creational pattern that might help if your objects are *individually* expensive to create. An alternative is the Proxy pattern which defers creation of an expensive object by creating a placeholder object (proxy object) until the real object is required; an example of *lazy loading*.

But you say that your data structure is trivial, so neither of the above is applicable: not even Proxy can avoid freezing the UI while doing many individually trivial memory allocations. You could use *lazy loading* to minimise the effect of many object constructions, as a commenter suggested. So if you need 1,000 objects on start-up but this is unacceptably slow, redesign the UI to look and behave as normal with only 100 objects. Then you only need to construct 100 objects *on start-up*; the rest can be constructed later.

When is 'later'? You have some options:

- On demand. As the user manipulates the UI, construct objects as required.
- Automatic but deferred construction. This could be when the application first signals that it is idle - the OnIdle event - after startup and the UI has been fully displayed. This event is raised many times in an application lifetime so obviously you'll need to check for the first of these.

Another possibility is to construct all 1,000 objects on a background thread, allowing the UI thread free to do a minimum of work in rendering the initial UI state. But this is probably only an option if you don't need to display any of the 1,000 objects at the initial stage.

Finally, there are resources on the web, eg. MSDN magazine, for general guidelines to minimising startup time, like only creating the minimum forms required.